# How do I show using math symbols "get quotient without remainder"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, for 10/3, I only want to get 3, not 3.333. Is there a math operation that does this?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

Comment: Try $\lfloor 10/3 \rfloor=3$. This is the "floor" operation and gets rid of any decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods to do this:
1. Use the floor function $\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor$
2. Subtract the remainder and then divide: $\frac{a - ({a \text{ mod } b})}{b}$

Answer (score 4):

Use the floor function, which takes a rational number and outputs the quotient (hence subtracts the remainder from the rational number): $\lfloor x \rfloor$, where $x$ is a given fraction.

So $\lfloor 10/3 \rfloor = 3$, e.g.

Comment: Go Vikes! ${}{}$

Comment: Today, @Asaf, it's the San Francisco 49'ers! First playoff game preceding the superbowl! ;-)

Comment: I see. I don't actually follow sports in Israel, let alone in other countries. I just recognized the Packers symbols from watching a lot of That '70s Show and How I Met Your Mother. :-P

Comment: @amWhy: needs another UV +1